# Where is the list of key names I can use in hwdb remapping?

Tags: linux, systemd

I'm remapping keyboard keys using a `.hwdb` file. All the guides I've found say to use the format `KEYBOARD_KEY_[scancode]=[key]`. But they never explain how to find the acceptable values for the right-hand side. Where can I locate them?

Additionally, can you just give it a keycode as a number instead of the name of the key?

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint in this case. But I didn't include that in the question, since a more generic answer would be helpful for more people coming across this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what version of the kernel you're running, but the keycode names and values come from here:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h